# Создание синхронного(асинхронного) метода Rx

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxandroid

Выполняю асинхронные запросы, и все работает. Ну есть нюанс, в метода `public void onComplete()` я вызываю метод `generateClan_Dannie(hashMap, clan_id);`(в нем еще несколько вызывается) для обработки данных. Они тоже все исправно работают, но дело в том что мой `ProgressDialog` перестает работать(крутиться), и приложение зависает пока выполняется метод. И я не понимаю принципа как его можно добавить в другой поток, чтоб отработал, так же как эти запросы.

```
  if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getActivity().getApplicationContext())) {

            final HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

            final ProgressDialog dialog;
            /**
         * Progress Dialog for User Interaction
         */
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setTitle("Сервер");
        dialog.setMessage("Получаем данные от сервера");


        final ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService("ru");


        Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> firstFlowable = api.getDannieClanRx(clan_id, application_id);

        Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> flowable = firstFlowable
                .flatMap(new Function<Response<ResponseBody>, Flowable<? extends Response<ResponseBody>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Flowable<? extends Response<ResponseBody>> apply(Response<ResponseBody> response) throws Exception {
                        // Log.d("TAG_DANNIE", response.body().string());
                        list = response.body().string();
                        clan_dannie.setDannieClanNew(generateDannieClan.generateDannieClan(list, clan_id));
                        Log.e("Tag", list);
                        return api.getPersonallyDannieClanPlayerRx(clan_dannie.getDannieClanNew().getMembersString2(), application_id)
                                .mergeWith(api.getTexnikaPlayer(clan_dannie.getDannieClanNew().getMembersString2(), application_id))
                                .mergeWith(api.getInfoTexnika(application_id));
                    }
                });

        Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> flowable2 = flowable
                .mergeWith(api.getRatingClanRx(clan_id, application_id));

        Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> flowable3 = flowable2
                .mergeWith(api.getYkrepClanRx(clan_id, application_id));

        flowable3
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new FlowableSubscriber<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                        //Показать диалог
                        dialog.show();
                        s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                        //Прилетел ответ
                        try {
                            String url =String.valueOf(responseBodyResponse.raw().request().url());
                            String response = responseBodyResponse.body().string();
                            Log.e("URL", url);
                            Log.e("TAG", response);
                            hashMap.put(url, response);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                        //Ошибка
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                        generateClan_Dannie(hashMap, clan_id); //Тут я обрабатываю результат (там несколько разных методов)
                        //Убрать диалог
                        //Dismiss Dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Intent intent;
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivityClan.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                });

    }
    else
    {
        Snackbar.make(parentView, "fail", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```